# how to deal with non-jsp methods in spring boot controller when user refresh

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, jsp

I just started working on java spring boot some days ago and currently I'm working on Spring Boot Web Application. Till now I have `Signup`, `Singin` and `Dashboard(Home Page)`. When user sign up successfully I redirect the user to login page, when user login successfully I redirect the user to Dashboard.
The problem is when the registration page load I'm calling `register()` method with `@RequestMapping`, complete method is below.
**Note:** Words with all upper case letters are static strings.

```
@RequestMapping(REGISTER)
public String register() {
    System.out.println("Register Working!!!!");

    return REGISTER;
}
```

Here in the above method the url becomes http://localhost:8080/register
**But** on the registration/signup page when user click on Register button I'm calling another method named `registerUser(Users user)` complete method is below

```
@PostMapping("registerUser")
public ModelAndView registerUser(Users user) {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    user.setIpAddress(AppUtils.getCurrentIp());

    if (isUserByUsernamePresent(user.getUsername()) || isUserByEmailPresent(user.getEmail())) {
        mv.setViewName(REGISTER);
        mv.addObject(MESSAGE_TYPE_ST, MESSAGE_TYPE_DANGER);
        mv.addObject(MESSAGE_Body_ST, "This username or email alreary exit!");
    } else {
        repo.save(user);
        Users tempUser = getUserDetail(user, "RegisterUser");
        if (user.getUsername().equals(tempUser.getUsername())) {
            mv.setViewName(INDEX);
            mv.addObject(MESSAGE_TYPE_ST, MESSAGE_TYPE_SUCCESS);
            mv.addObject(MESSAGE_Body_ST, "You have successfully created an account! check your email to confirm your registration");
        } else {
            mv.setViewName(REGISTER);
            mv.addObject(MESSAGE_TYPE_ST, MESSAGE_TYPE_DANGER);
            mv.addObject(MESSAGE_Body_ST, "Something went wrong, please try again or contact us!");
        }
    }
```

So here `registerUser` is not a jsp page but the method to register new user. Now the url becomes http://localhost:8080/registerUser. At this time if user refresh the page user get bunch of error code because `registerUser` is not a jsp page so the user can't call it directly.

Here comes my question in this scenario how to deal with http://localhost:8080/registerUser if its not jsp page. One solution that I have in mind is I should have only one method `register` or `registerUser` and check if the user object is null then consider the call is from loading the page OR if user object is not null then the call is from register button so I should do the save user stuff.

If there is a nicer approach please let me know. Any effort will be appreciated. If there is need to expose more code let me know.

**Edit:** `@PostMapping("registerUser")` I'm setting index as a view name if registration is successful OR register if registration is unsuccessful. So should the url not be index or register respectively?

Comment: I am confused. And so are you I think. *At this time if user refresh the page user get bunch of error code because registerUser is not a jsp page so the user can't call it directly.* Any request to http://localhost:8080/registerUser  is going through that controller whether it's form post, page refresh or otherwise. So that kind of invalidates your question *in this scenario how to deal with http://localhost:8080/registerUser if its not jsp page*

Comment: by jsp I means the front end i.e. `index.jsp` or `register.jsp` etc. not the back end controller

Comment: Sorry the fron end only knows about URLs. You need to post the error and be aware that, as alluded to in the answer below, refreshing after form post submits the form a second time.

Comment: ok, can we pass data to other pages with redirect request?

Comment: Redirect and/or flash attributes: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-redirect-and-forward. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this way to resolve the refresh error. From registerUser method once you have completed your processing call the GET method (redirect to controllers other GET method) to redirect to needed page so if you refresh the page call will be for that get method not post(registerUser)